# Azure Traffic Manager Multiple Websites

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

Currently, I am trying to setup a traffic manager profile for our company needs. Although I read the articles and documentation, I did no find an answer. Our goal is the following:

1. Route traffic based on domain name/website:

   abc.com  - routed to **West Europe** / **West US** is a backup

   def.com  - routed to **West US** / **West Europe** is a backup

Do we need to create separate traffic manager profile for each website we want to route to these regions. As I understand with custom headers it is possible to monitor different websites inside the profile, but obviously not to direct traffic using different rules for each website.

Probably, I am missing something out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure traffic manager supports the following traffic [routing methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods):

**Priority**, **Weighted**, **Performance**, **Geographic**, **Multivalue**, **Subnet**.

If you want to direct traffic based on the domain name, you need to create a separate traffic manager profile for each domain. Then create two endpoints by selecting Priority routing rules in each profile.

In addition, you could have a look at the [Azure front door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview). With Front Door, you can transform your global consumer and enterprise applications into robust, high-performing personalized modern applications with content that reach a global audience through Azure. It supports [URL-path based routing for requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching). You also could [assign priorities to your different backends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-backend-pool#backends) when you want to use a primary service backend for all traffic.

Comment: Hi Nancy, 

Thank you for the update/comment. I considered previously Azure Frond Door as an option, however, still I don't see an option for multiple subdomains/websites to be added and pointed to regions as backend endpoints. As you stated in your message, I will have to create different traffic manager profiles for each subdomain/website in order to forward traffic to primary/backup regions.

Comment: I mean if you are using Azure front door, you can add a custom domain then create a routing rule to match the custom domain. Then the process flow will be from two custom domains---two backend pool(each pool have two websites in two different regions)---two matched routing rules in one Azure front door. But it seems that it's much more complex configurations than using two Azure TM.